# SQL Server data to PostgreSQL on insert sql trigger

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, triggers, msdtc

I am trying to move data from MS SQL Server (2014) to PostgreSQL (12.6) by using the psqlodbc(12_02_0000-x64) odbc driver and Postgresql as linked server in SSMS on my local machine.

The goal is move data inserted in a SQL Server table to a PGSQL table by using an insert trigger on the sql server table. But I always get a MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator error:

***Msg 8522, Level 18, State 1, Line 1
Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.***

A simple insert into .. select works fine:

```
INSERT INTO [POSTGRESQL].[MyPgDb].[MyPgSchema].[MyPgTable](Id, StartTime, EndTime, TestMessage)
(SELECT [Id], [StartTime], [EndTime], [TestMessage] FROM [MySqlDb].[dbo].[MySqlTable]);
```

This is the trigger I am using:

```
USE [MySqlDb]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TriggerInsertMsg]    Script Date: 02.07.2021 09:15:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerInsertMsg]
    ON [MySqlDb].[dbo].[MySqlTable]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN TRAN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- SET XACT_ABORT ON??
        INSERT INTO [POSTGRESQL].[MyPgDb].[MyPgSchema].[MyPgTable](Id, StartTime, EndTime, TestMessage)
        (SELECT [inserted].Id, [inserted].StartTime, [inserted].EndTime, [inserted].TestMessage FROM INSERTED)
    COMMIT;
```

I tried the following actions without any success:

- Using `BEGIN TRAN.. COMMIT;` instead of `BEGIN..END` in the trigger
- Starting MSDTC service
- Enabling MSDTC in firewall
- Enabling XA Transactions in dcomcnfg
- using `SET XACT_ABORT ON`

The trigger works fine when I replace the linked pg server by an other SQL table. Do I have to adjust some PostgreSQL configuration to enable transactions coming from the SQL server and/or MS DTC? Where can I find the reference of the error (Msg 8522, Level 18, State 1, Line 1)?

Comment: Honestly, I would avoid doing this in a `TRIGGER`. If the `TRIGGER` fails, for what ever reason, so too will the `INSERT` Also, as the error says, the `INSERT` on the remote instance will be in the same transaction, and if the instance can't therefore create the distributed transaction is needs it'll fail; which is what appears to be happening here.

Comment: You would likely bebetter off with perhaps including a column in your data to denote it has been "copied", and then a process that regularly "copies" the pending data from the SQL Server instance to the PostgreSQL instance, and then marks the data in SQL Server as "copied". Otherwise, if latency isn't permissible, you'll likely want to look into replication or mirroring solutions.

Comment: The BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT transaction in the trigger is redundant because triggers always execute in the transaction context of the statement that fired the trigger. If you don't really need distributed transactions, change the linked server option: `EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false';`

Comment: For performance reasons, you may also want to add `IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)) RETURN;` at the top of the trigger

Comment: You must begin by a **BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION.**

Comment: @SQLpro `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` leads to the same msdtc error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Larnu. I will have to check whether it is possible to add such a "copied" column as I then have to adjust a working data model. Can you please provide some more information how to achieve my intend by using replication or mirroring?

Comment: Setting up mirroring or replication are questions for [dba.se] @AndreS. .

Comment: @Larnu Would a stored procedure that synchronizes the sql server and postgresql dbs and is called regularly by a task/thread be a legit substitute for the insert trigger?